# aes128cbc encryption method in java code switch to lua code but have difference

Tags: java, lua, openresty

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

/**
 * <h3>aestools</h3>
 *
 * @author wangzhe
 * @version 1.0.2
 * @createTime 2022/8/23 15:30
 */
public class App {

    private static final String TOKEN = "6e4292f87a5c4c34";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String encrypt = encrypt("2000.0", TOKEN);
            System.out.println(encrypt);

            String decrypt = decrypt(encrypt, TOKEN);
            System.out.println(decrypt);

        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * encrypt
     * @param content 
     * @param token 
     * @return 
     */
    public static String encrypt(String content,String token)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        byte[] raw = token.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(raw);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe(encrypted);
        return new String(encodeBase64, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) ;
    }

    /**
     * decrypt
     * @param content
     * @param token
     * @return
     */
    public static String decrypt(String content,String token)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        byte[] raw = token.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(raw);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(content));
        return new String(encrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

}
```

run the java code, the encryption result is "zVRUDe0VY-0CdMFJXcOJ3A",
decryption result is '2000.0'

the following i use encryption method in openresty using lua:

```
local function AES128CBC_Encrypt(price, key, iv)
        local aes128cbc, _ = aes:new(key, nil, aes.cipher(128, 'cbc'), {iv = string.rep(string.char(0), 16)})
        return aes128cbc:encrypt(aes128cbc, price)

end
```

but the encrption result is "-^c�6���|��=" which is diff from the java code result. i guess should do some processing on the token first. but i dont know.

and, i attach aes.lua code in openresty:

```
local asn1 = require "resty.asn1"
local ffi = require "ffi"
local ffi_new = ffi.new
local ffi_gc = ffi.gc
local ffi_str = ffi.string
local ffi_copy = ffi.copy
local C = ffi.C
local setmetatable = setmetatable
--local error = error
local type = type


local _M = { _VERSION = '0.11' }

local mt = { __index = _M }


ffi.cdef[[
typedef struct engine_st ENGINE;

typedef struct evp_cipher_st EVP_CIPHER;
typedef struct evp_cipher_ctx_st EVP_CIPHER_CTX;

typedef struct env_md_ctx_st EVP_MD_CTX;
typedef struct env_md_st EVP_MD;

const EVP_MD *EVP_md5(void);
const EVP_MD *EVP_sha(void);
const EVP_MD *EVP_sha1(void);
const EVP_MD *EVP_sha224(void);
const EVP_MD *EVP_sha256(void);
const EVP_MD *EVP_sha384(void);
const EVP_MD *EVP_sha512(void);

const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_128_ecb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_128_cbc(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_128_cfb1(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_128_cfb8(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_128_cfb128(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_128_ofb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_128_ctr(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_192_ecb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_192_cbc(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_192_cfb1(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_192_cfb8(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_192_cfb128(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_192_ofb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_192_ctr(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_256_ecb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_256_cbc(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_256_cfb1(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_256_cfb8(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_256_cfb128(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_256_ofb(void);

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
void EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *a);

int EVP_EncryptInit_ex(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx,const EVP_CIPHER *cipher,
        ENGINE *impl, unsigned char *key, const unsigned char *iv);

int EVP_EncryptUpdate(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out, int *outl,
        const unsigned char *in, int inl);

int EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out, int *outl);

int EVP_DecryptInit_ex(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx,const EVP_CIPHER *cipher,
        ENGINE *impl, unsigned char *key, const unsigned char *iv);

int EVP_DecryptUpdate(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out, int *outl,
        const unsigned char *in, int inl);

int EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *outm, int *outl);

int EVP_BytesToKey(const EVP_CIPHER *type,const EVP_MD *md,
        const unsigned char *salt, const unsigned char *data, int datal,
        int count, unsigned char *key,unsigned char *iv);
]]

local hash
hash = {
    md5 = C.EVP_md5(),
    sha1 = C.EVP_sha1(),
    sha224 = C.EVP_sha224(),
    sha256 = C.EVP_sha256(),
    sha384 = C.EVP_sha384(),
    sha512 = C.EVP_sha512()
}
_M.hash = hash

local cipher
cipher = function (size, _cipher)
    local _size = size or 128
    local _cipher = _cipher or "cbc"
    local func = "EVP_aes_" .. _size .. "_" .. _cipher
    if C[func] then
        return { size=_size, cipher=_cipher, method=C[func]()}
    else
        return nil
    end
end
_M.cipher = cipher

function _M.new(self, key, salt, _cipher, _hash, hash_rounds)
    local encrypt_ctx = C.EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()
    if encrypt_ctx == nil then
        return nil, "no memory"
    end

    ffi_gc(encrypt_ctx, C.EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free)

    local decrypt_ctx = C.EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()
    if decrypt_ctx == nil then
        return nil, "no memory"
    end

    ffi_gc(decrypt_ctx, C.EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free)

    local _cipher = _cipher or cipher()
    local _hash = _hash or hash.md5
    local hash_rounds = hash_rounds or 1
    local _cipherLength = _cipher.size/8
    local gen_key = ffi_new("unsigned char[?]",_cipherLength)
    local gen_iv = ffi_new("unsigned char[?]",_cipherLength)

    if type(_hash) == "table" then
        if not _hash.iv or #_hash.iv ~= 16 then
          return nil, "bad iv"
        end

        if _hash.method then
            local tmp_key = _hash.method(key)

            if #tmp_key ~= _cipherLength then
                return nil, "bad key length"
            end

            ffi_copy(gen_key, tmp_key, _cipherLength)

        elseif #key ~= _cipherLength then
            return nil, "bad key length"

        else
            ffi_copy(gen_key, key, _cipherLength)
        end

        ffi_copy(gen_iv, _hash.iv, 16)

    else
        if salt and #salt ~= 8 then
            return nil, "salt must be 8 characters or nil"
        end

        if C.EVP_BytesToKey(_cipher.method, _hash, salt, key, #key,
                            hash_rounds, gen_key, gen_iv)
            ~= _cipherLength
        then
            return nil
        end
    end

    if C.EVP_EncryptInit_ex(encrypt_ctx, _cipher.method, nil,
      gen_key, gen_iv) == 0 or
      C.EVP_DecryptInit_ex(decrypt_ctx, _cipher.method, nil,
      gen_key, gen_iv) == 0 then
        return nil
    end

    return setmetatable({
      _encrypt_ctx = encrypt_ctx,
      _decrypt_ctx = decrypt_ctx
      }, mt)
end


function _M.encrypt(self, s)
    local s_len = #s
    local max_len = s_len + 16
    local buf = ffi_new("unsigned char[?]", max_len)
    local out_len = ffi_new("int[1]")
    local tmp_len = ffi_new("int[1]")
    local ctx = self._encrypt_ctx

    if C.EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, nil, nil, nil, nil) == 0 then
        return nil
    end

    if C.EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, buf, out_len, s, s_len) == 0 then
        return nil
    end

    if C.EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, buf + out_len[0], tmp_len) == 0 then
        return nil
    end

    return ffi_str(buf, out_len[0] + tmp_len[0])
end


function _M.decrypt(self, s)
    local s_len = #s
    local buf = ffi_new("unsigned char[?]", s_len)
    local out_len = ffi_new("int[1]")
    local tmp_len = ffi_new("int[1]")
    local ctx = self._decrypt_ctx

    if C.EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, nil, nil, nil, nil) == 0 then
      return nil
    end

    if C.EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, buf, out_len, s, s_len) == 0 then
      return nil
    end

    if C.EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, buf + out_len[0], tmp_len) == 0 then
        return nil
    end

    return ffi_str(buf, out_len[0] + tmp_len[0])
end


return _M
```

Comment: You're applying Base64 encoding in the java code and not in the lua code. Apply it with the lua code as well - without it, you can't print raw bytes, you just get a bunch of question marks as you are now.

Comment: i tried ngx.encode_base64 the lua encryption result and is "LV5jhTbJ748P73yKAh/sPQ==", still diff from java result... 5555

Comment: your lua code uses 0 as IV, your java code uses the key as IV. Both are crypto-wise suboptimal. If they aren't the same, the crypto result won't be either, obviously. If this is all gobbledygook to you, I'm not sure you should be messing with any of this. The problem with handrolling your own crypto protocols, even if based on well known algorithms, is that if you mess it up, you won't know until the data is compromised.

Comment: thank u too much i make the key as iv to run lua code and i got it.